# List root directories - Java vs. Groovy different output

Tags: java, groovy

I try to list root directories with Groovy. There I only get local hard drives. The same statement in Java return local hard drives and all network drives. Anyone have an idea why Groovy behaves differently?

Working with:

- Groovy Version: 4.0.4 JVM: 1.8.0_151 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 10
- java version "1.8.0_151"

Groovy:

```
for (File root : File.listRoots()) {
    System.out.println(root);
}
```

Output:

```
B:\
C:\
E:\
```

Java:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        
        for (File root : File.listRoots()) {
            System.out.println(root);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
B:\
C:\
E:\
J:\
P:\
S:\
U:\
V:\
X:\
Z:\
```

Comment: Do you see the same thing with `FileSystems.getDefault().getRootDirectories()`?

Comment: @Slaw I get the same result: [B:\, C:\, E:\]

Comment: You get the "same result" as in the same _problematic_ output, or you get the "same result" as in the same output in Java _and_ Groovy?

Comment: I get this result in Groovy (with FileSystems): [B:\, C:\, E:]  

In Java I get also the complete list (also with FileSystems): B:\, C:\, E:  ....  Z:\

Comment: what differentiates visible and not visible drives? for me groovy shows all.

Comment: B,C & E are local drives. All others are network Drives: J - Z. I have access to all drives in Windows.